# Form ShowDialog Issue When Drag From TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, draggable, showdialog

I have implemented Tab Control drag drop.Where, when i click on Tab Control and  drag a new form is opened with the data of Tabpage.

The problem is if i keep form.Show().The form shows drag appearance and moves with the mouse.
However if i use form.ShowDialog() then form simply opens and drag effect does not take place.

In such case i am able to drag only when i click on form header and drag it again.
I have written below code for the same.

```
   protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == NativeMethods.WM_MOVING)
        {
            DockUndockTabpage(m);
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);

        switch (m.Msg)
        {

            case NativeMethods.WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 1)
                {
                    if (!captured)
                    {
                        Point pt = tabControl.PointToScreen((Cursor.Position));
                        Point newPosition = new Point(pt.X - dragOffset.X, pt.Y - dragOffset.Y);
                        this.Location = newPosition;
                    }
                    NativeMethods.RECT rc = new NativeMethods.RECT(this.Bounds);
                    IntPtr lParam = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(rc));
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(rc, lParam, true);
                    NativeMethods.SendMessage(this.Handle, NativeMethods.WM_MOVING, IntPtr.Zero, lParam);
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lParam);
                }
                break;

            case NativeMethods.WM_SETCURSOR:
                captured = true;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

There are two methods that do docking and Undocking, To and from the original form respectively.

```
private void DockToTab()
    {
        if (!tabControl.TabPages.Contains(tabPageToInsert))
        {
            tabControl.TabPages.Insert(tabID, tabPageToInsert);
            tabControl.SelectedTab = tabPageToInsert;
            tabControl.Capture = true;
            this.Close();
        }
    }

private  static void UnDockFromTab()
    {
        if (formToShow.Visible || formToShow.IsDisposed)
            return;
        formToShow.tabControl.TabPages.Remove(formToShow.tabPageToInsert);
        formToShow.Capture = true;
        formToShow.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Kinldy help.

Comment: This code looks awfully random, hard to see how it can work.  Your user also will never figure out by himself that he's supposed to drag a tab control.  Create a sane and usable UI, just add a View button to the tab page.

Comment: @HansPassant I have just given a snippet of the code to Undock and Dock the Form.When user click on TabPage Header and drags it a new form is opened.I have added image on Tabpage Header to signify that this tabpage is draggable.

Comment: I need to know why Drag works for Show() properly and not for ShowDialog().If needed i can put the project to get more idea.

Comment: ShowDialog() method lock all events. If you want not stop other form events you must use Show() method.

Comment: @nercan Ohh Probably thats the reason i am not able to drag the form in the desired manner since internal events are not called properly..?

Comment: @nercan What could be work around please suggest.

Comment: Why ShowDialog ? u can use Show method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I note my objection against this kind of UI, it is very undiscoverable.  Some code to make it work anyway.  Basic things you have to do is to detect the user starting to drag the mouse on the TabControl.  Once detected, you can then create the form on-the-fly.  Put it at the same location as the tab so it looks like it was dragged from the tab itself.  You then need a trick to convince the form that it is being dragged by its caption bar, you do so by posting the WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN message.  This worked well:

```
    private Point TabMouseDownPos;

    private void tabControl1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        TabMouseDownPos = e.Location;
    }

    private void tabControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        // Detect start of drag
        if (e.Button != System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) return;
        int dx = e.X - TabMouseDownPos.X;
        int dy = e.Y - TabMouseDownPos.Y;
        if (Math.Abs(dx) >= SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Width ||
            Math.Abs(dy) >= SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Height) {
            // Start drag, create the form at the same position as the tab
            Form form = CreateTabForm();
            form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            var tabpos = tabControl1.GetTabRect(tabControl1.SelectedIndex);
            form.Location = tabControl1.PointToScreen(new Point(tabpos.Left + dx, tabpos.Top + dy));
            // Juggle the mouse so it now starts dragging the form
            tabControl1.Capture = false;
            PostMessage(form.Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)2, IntPtr.Zero);
            form.ShowDialog();          
        }
    }
    private Form CreateTabForm() {
        // Return form object that matches tabControl1.SelectedIndex
        //...
        return new Form2();
    }

    private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0x00a1;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
```

Work on the CreateTabForm() method to create an instance of the form that matches the tabControl.SelectedIndex property value.

Comment: Pasant. This worked for me.Thanks a ton sir.I was stuck for hours finding solution for this..

Comment: I have a question or rather doubt.Can PostMessage cause any problem if we use it.As in my case.It solved the drag issue.but will it effect any other event in some ways.Kindly throw some knowledge on this.Thank you.